# Retrieving contacts in list view and displaying the name and phone number in next activity with click action

Tags: android

I have got the code where through content provider i am retrieving the phone contacts and displaying them in list format.
I want to display the phone no and name of the particular person in next activity when i click on the list format contacts from first activity. I am getting errors in this its not able to perform click operation and display it on to next activity Please help me with this.

Here is the first Activity through i am display the contacts through content provider.

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.database.Cursor;

import android.net.Uri;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.AdapterView;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import android.widget.TextView;



public class MsatActivity extends ListActivity 

{

TextView ContactsTV;

ListView lv;

Cursor c;

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = 

Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1557");


public void onListItemClick(View v)

{

    Intent outData = new Intent(this,Full.class); 

//   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, outData);

     startActivity(outData);

}

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      Uri myContacts = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;         

      c = getContentResolver().query(myContacts, new String[]

      {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,

      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,

      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER}     

      , null, null, null);


      String[] columns = new String[]                                   

              { 

              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,

              ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};        

             int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2};



            SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new 

SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.listitems, c, columns, to); 

            setListAdapter(mAdapter); 

             lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemClickListener() 

             {



public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 

{

 int rowId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));

Uri outURI = Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI.toString() + "/" + rowId); 

Intent outData = new Intent(); 

outData.setData(outURI);

 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, outData);

 finish();

 }

             });

  }

  }
```

Here is the second activity.......

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.database.Cursor;

import android.net.Uri;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;



public class Full extends Activity

{



    private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;

    String name;

    Cursor cursor;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

        Button getContacts = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        getContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnItemClickListener() 

        {



            public void onClick(View v)

            {

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,

                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);



            }

        });

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)

        {

            switch (requestCode)

            {

            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:





                try {

                    Uri result = data.getData();

                    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();



                    //Get Name

                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(result, null, null, null, null);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst())

                    {

                        name = 
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    } 

                }

                    catch (Exception e) 

                    {



                    }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really can't figure out your code at all. The first activity seems to be creating an Intent to start the Full Activity, but it has two "onclick" methods and it does a setResult() and finish() even though it never did getIntent()!

The second activity creates an ACTION_PICK Intent for the entire Phone table, and handles the return by doing a query on the result, which should be the contact ID of the contact whose # the user picked. I don't think it's the entire URI, though; you should verify that through debug. You then try to get the DISPLAY_NAME for this contact.

Fine, but I don't see why you need the first Activity at all.

I posted some instructions on using the Contacts Provider somewhere else on Stackoverflow; just search for android and ContactsContract.